# How to list collections in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, go

In golang..
I get list mongodb database name below..

```
filter := bson.D{{}}
dbs, _ := client.ListDatabaseNames(context.TODO(), filter)
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", dbs)
```

But, I want to get list collections name.

Answer (score 5):

How about [ListCollectionNames](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Database.ListCollectionNames)?

Here's an example from the documentation. I added some placeholder lines that you need to replace by your client connection code and getting a database:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
)

func main() {
    // Placeholder:
    //
    // Connect to MongoDB, handle error
    client, err := mongo.connect(....)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    // Obtain the DB, by name. db will have the type
    // *mongo.Database
    db := client.Database("name-of-your-DB")
    
    // use a filter to only select capped collections
    result, err := db.ListCollectionNames(
        context.TODO(),
        bson.D{{"options.capped", true}})

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    for _, coll := range result {
        fmt.Println(coll)
    }
}
```

Comment: `result, err := db.ListCollectionNames(` panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference..

Comment: Do not blindly run this code, it lacks initialization of the `db`. Insert the relevant snippet in your code

Comment: @neohwang: I updated the code sample to pinpoint the placeholder code you'll need to replace with your Mongo connection and getting a DB from the client